# Java write csv-String to Excel

Tags: java, excel, string, csv, apache-poi

in my program i want to write an String to *.xlsx

Example for the String:

> a,b,c,d,e,,f,\na,b,c,d,e,,f,\n

I want to write an Excel file which looks like this:[image]

How can I do this?

```
private void createExcel() throws Exception {
    //Create blank workbook
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
    //Create a blank sheet
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
```

How can I create the rows and columns from my csvString?

```
    //Write the workbook in file system
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("FilePath.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("*.xlsx written successfully" );
}
```

I'm thankful for any help

Comment: By studying docs/tutorials and starting to write code and *try* experimenting?!

Answer (score 1):

Using `XSSFSheet.createRow()`, you can create rows as required.

In your case, you would have to split the string by `,\n` and make a `XSSFSheet.createRow()` call for each element of the resulting array.

Using `XSSFRow.createCell()`, you can create cells, for which a split by `,` would be required. To set the value, `Cell.setCellValue()` has to be invoked with each comma separated part.

Simple example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_spreadsheets.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the advice first splitting at `\n`- I tried splitting at `,`and then write the Excel - if I come up with working Code i will post it here

Answer (score 0):

```
private void createExcel() throws Exception {
    //Create blank workbook
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
    //Create a blank sheet
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet_1 = workbook.createSheet("Excel Sheet");

    ArrayList<String> arrRows = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Text.split("\n")));

    for (int i = 0; i < arrRows.size(); i++) {

        XSSFRow row = spreadsheet_1.createRow(i);

        ArrayList<String> arrElement = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrRows.get(i).split(",")));

        for(int j = 0; j < arrElement.size(); j++) {

            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
            cell.setCellValue(arrElement.get(j));

        }           
    }
    //Write the workbook in file system
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("FilePath.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("*.xlsx written successfully" );
}
```

Like @Naveed S said first I split my Text at every `\N` and create a Row for each element. Then I Split the elements at `,`and create Cells

Thanks for the help and suggestion it really helped me